# BoneCP 0.7.1.RELEASE and hibernate 4.1.*

Tags: java, hibernate, bonecp

I try to add BoneCP to hibernate and have:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProvider
```

I couldn't find this interface in new hibernate packages and have 2 questions :

1) Could you share link or example how to manually configure BoneCP 0.7.1 with hibernate  4.1.*? (I only added connection.provider_class=com.jolbox.bonecp.provider.BoneCPConnectionProvider in hibernate.cfg.xml)

2) Someone tested BoneCP 0.8.0-alpha1? It's work good with new hibarnate, but has scary "alpha1" in version

Thank for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The JVM cannot find the `ConnectionProvider` interface because it moved to a different package from [Hibernate 3](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/connection/ConnectionProvider.html) to [Hibernate 4](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider.html), so you'll need to use BoneCP 0.8.0-alpha1.

2) So far it hasn't caused me any problems, but others should contribute their experience.

Comment: For Hibernate 4.3.x I had to get the source code and fix a broken import, and change the version of Hibernate specified. Hibernate repackaged the dang ConnectionProvider class again.