# Hibernate 4 ConnectionProvider Class not found

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, classnotfoundexception

I just updated Hibernate in my application to 4.3.4 (from 3.X), which caused some problems. The first was the new method of creating a sessionFactory, which I resolved.

The next problem, which I'm finding nothing about, is that I am now getting a ClassNotFoundException on org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProvider

It should be noted that I'm using BoneCP (0.7.1) for my connection pool, which was working before the upgrade.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm pretty new to hibernate (I'm working on implementing it as a POC), and I may have left out some important details from my description here as such. 
I don't need it to be the newest version, so I can revert back, but it would be nice to have the latest and greatest :)

Thanks!

Hibernate.cfg.xml snippet (with sensitive info replaced):

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">foo</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">bob</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">bar</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">package.path.MySQLCustomDialect</property>

        <!-- Bonecp connection pool -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.jolbox.bonecp.provider.BoneCPConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="bonecp.maxConnectionAgeInMinutes">5</property>
        <property name="bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes">0</property>
        and so on ...
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-110" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/connection/ConnectionProvider
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2895)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:222)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at foo.utils.HibernateUtils.<clinit>(HibernateUtils.java:16)
    at foo.objects.building.BuildingHelper.getBuildingByID(BuildingHelper.java:225)
    at foo.objects.inventory.LocationInformation.<init>(LocationInformation.java:36)
    at foo.objects.computermanagementframework.peripheral.PeripheralHelper.readLocation(PeripheralHelper.java:154)
    at foo.objects.computermanagementframework.peripheral.PeripheralHelper.refresh(PeripheralHelper.java:556)
    at foo.server.initialization.InitializeServerThread.run(InitializeServerThread.java:298)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProvider
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: do you use maven to build the project?

Comment: is the library (jar) containing class `com.jolbox.bonecp.provider.BoneCPConnectionProvider` present in your build path?

Comment: Yes, it's a maven project. And I have bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE and bonecp-provider-0.7.1.RELEASE in my build path (also maven dependencies)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate keeps changing the package containing the `ConnectionProvider` base class. It changed from version 3 to 4 and has changed again with verson 4.3.
As @teresa-carrigan mentions in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10377516/3080094), you'll have to compile the latest [BoneCPConnectionProvider.java](https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/blob/master/bonecp-hbnprovider/src/main/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/provider/BoneCPConnectionProvider.java) (currently supporting Hibernate 4.3.1) and use that.

Or use Hibernate version 4.2.12.Final and see if that works with BoneCP 0.8 (as explained in the aforementioned answer).

Comment: Going back to 4.2.10 with BoneCP 0.8 worked. Thanks for the tip!