# hibernate4.1 + spring3.2 + boneCP

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, connection-pooling, bonecp

app context looks like

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.some.domain.to.scan" /> 
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${url}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${username}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${password}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.l2_cache.enabled}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.l2_cache.enabled}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">/settings/ehcache-hibernate-settings.xml</prop>
            <prop key="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">/settings/ehcache-hibernate-settings.xml</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">com.jolbox.bonecp.provider.BoneCPConnectionProvider</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.idleMaxAge">240</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriod">60</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.partitionCount">2</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.acquireIncrement">5</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition">20</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.minConnectionsPerPartition">10</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.statementsCacheSize">50</prop>
            <prop key="bonecp.releaseHelperThreads">2</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    <qualifier value="dbdomain"/>
</bean>
```

while gradle imports include latest version of bonecp-provider, bonecp and bonecp-spring along with spring 3.2.0.RELEASE and hibernate 4.1.12.Final

seemed like everything is in place but when i run the app (jetty server), it throw the following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [app/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/connection/ConnectionProvider
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:589)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
```

any help on how to correctly setup bonecp would be helpful.

**UPDATE**

after resolving so dependency issues with bonecp I am getting a new error as the follows:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [app/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
```

a few minor changes to app context were also made but i believe they have nothing to do with the error i am getting

the changes were

```
<prop key="bonecp.idleMaxAge">240</prop>
<prop key="bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriod">60</prop>
```

to

```
<prop key="bonecp.idleMaxAgeInMinutes">5</prop>
<prop key="bonecp.idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes">3</prop>
```

Comment: The BoneCP version needs to match with the Hibernate version, see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23018179/3080094)

Comment: i am using bonecp 0.8.0.RELEASE with hibernate 4.1.12

Answer (score 1):

This class has been moved to the following package:

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi
```

If you are using Maven run the following command:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

And check how many hibernate-core versions you have in your project. You might want to exclude the hibernate dependency from the spring dependency declarations.

Your issue is caused by this [BoneCP issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bonecp/+bug/928487).

So you need to update to BoneCP 0.80.

For the XADataSource unwrapping exception you should try [this solution](http://www.coderanch.com/t/581183/Spring/Spring-Hibernate-transaction-Management-unwrap).

Comment: just for clarification:
hibernate.connection.provider_class has moved to org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi?

Comment: also as for hibernate-core versions i have just the  4.1.12.Final

I ran 

'gradle dependencies | grep hibernate-core'

got 

'+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.12.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.12.Final (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.12.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.12.Final (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.12.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.12.Final (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.12.Final
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.1.12.Final (*)'

Comment: @abroy Verified with the relevant documentation, BoneCP 0.8.0-RELEASE with the bonecp-provider JAR should work with Hibernate 4.1. BoneCP provider source is [here](https://github.com/wwadge/bonecp/blob/bonecp-parent-0.8.0.RELEASE/bonecp-hbnprovider/src/main/java/com/jolbox/bonecp/provider/BoneCPConnectionProvider.java) and Hibernate 4.1 ApiDocs for `ConnectionProvider` is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider.html)

Comment: @vanOekel It seemed I also had bonecp0.7.1.RELEASE in my dependency tree but cleared those out. now only 0.8.0, that being said when i ran my server again, this time i got a different error as the following

'Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [app/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]'

Comment: @VladMihalcea Regarding the unwrapping exception, i am not sure whether the solution you pointed to me is the actual issue, nevertheless i did change 

_<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.some.domain.to.scan" />_ 

to 

**<property name="packagesToScan"> 
<list><value>com.some.domain.to.scan</value>/list>
</property>**

As per the solution provided. 
But still getting the same error