# Maven/Spring/Hibernate NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.JdbcServices.getConnectionProvider()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

First, I don't usually work with Java, but have in the past, so I'm a little bit out of my comfort zone. I have a Spring and Hibernate project that I'm working on, and it has a fatal error when starting. I can clone this same repo to another Macbook Pro (same as this one) and import into eclipse, maven clean install, run on server (tomcat config) and it works.

```
Jan 20, 2016 3:45:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mssqlEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-mssql.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.JdbcServices.getConnectionProvider()Lorg/hibernate/engine/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:741)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mssqlEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-mssql.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.JdbcServices.getConnectionProvider()Lorg/hibernate/engine/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:438)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:277)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1500)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.JdbcServices.getConnectionProvider()Lorg/hibernate/engine/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider;
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.use42Api(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:80)
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.integrate(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1744)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:290)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 34 more
```

Tomcat 7.0.64

Maven Dependency Tree

```
$ mvn dependency:tree

[INFO] +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.6.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-odm:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core-tiger:jar:2.0.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:jar:3.2.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:jar:3.2.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung:lutung:jar:0.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.6:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] \- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:jar:2.15:compile
[INFO]    +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.15:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.15:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]    \- org.jvnet.mimepull:mimepull:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1:49.357s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 21 11:15:00 EST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/307M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Maven

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 08:51:28-0500)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Java

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

I took the following steps:

```
$ git clone http://github.com/repo
$ cd repo
$ git checkout branch
$ mvn clean install
```

I deployed to Tomcat with the web gui and it would not start.
I cleaned the repo rebuilt everything, and tried from within Eclipse entirely, even having it handle Tomcat, and I get the same result. I deleted the ~/.m2/repository folder several times when cleaning and I always end up with the same error.

On the other machine, it gets this error occasionally and a clean install fixes it. The other machine is running Maven 3.3.3 and Java 1.7.0_79.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018179/hibernate-4-connectionprovider-class-not-found

Comment: Can you add the the output of ```mvn dependency:tree``` to your post.

Comment: Thanks, We are Borg, I read that post during my search, I will give it another read now. Everything points to a version mismatch between spring and hibernate, but I can run the exact setup on another machine and it works is what is confusing me the most.

Karthikeyan I am asking if I can post that output now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem the culprit is `org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core`. Remove  `org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:jar:3.2.0.GA:compile` from your pom.xml and it will work in JDK 8.

Comment: Thank you! I downgraded to 1.7.0_79 and it runs properly.

Comment: You could also upgrade your Usertype version reference to 4.0.0.GA or 5.0.0.GA to fix the problem, as noted in their [release notes](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html).